# Handsontable - Pikaday week numbers

Tags: javascript, handsontable, week-number, pikaday

I am using the pikaday calendar in Handsontable and want to include the week number on the drop down calendar. This option is supported by Pikaday

```
showWeekNumber: true
```

But I don't know how to pass this parameter to Pikaday from the Handsontable config.